# Remove white space between plots and table in grid.arrange

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

I would like to remove the large spacing that is inserted by default between the plots and the table in a grid.arrange, as shown in the MWE hereafter:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

list1=data.frame(mtcars[1:3, ])  # Dummy data
p1 = ggplot(list1, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()  # Dummy plot
p2 = ggplot(list1, aes(disp,hp)) + geom_point()  # Dummy plot
plots <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2,nrow=2)

table <- tableGrob(list1)
grid.arrange(plots, table)
```

I suspect this behaviour is due to the tableGrob, but I couldn't find any answer treating this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299496/reduce-space-between-grid-arrange-plots

Comment: Not exactly, it behaves differently between two ggplots that between a plot and a tableGrob. But thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing space between two plots in grid.arrange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146735/reducing-space-between-two-plots-in-grid-arrange)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`grid.arrange()` by default allocates equal space for each cell. If you want a tight fit around a specific grob, you should query its size, and pass it explicitly,

```
library(grid)
th <- sum(table$heights) # note: grobHeights.gtable is inaccurate
grid.arrange(plots, table, heights = unit.c(unit(1, "null"), th))
```

[image]

Comment: this answer fails me with: `Error in arrangeGrob(...) : could not find function "unit.c"`

Answer (score 3):

I actually found the parameter ruling the spacing between grobs: heights, see line below

```
grid.arrange(plots, table, heights=c(5,1))
```

Comment: I found this didn't actually address the white space issue, it just scales the graphics for the first and second to be 5:1 ratio.