# R remove whitespace between levelplot grobs

Tags: r, gridextra, levelplot, rastervis

I have a plot with rasterVis::levelplots above other rasterVis::levelplots.

There is too much whitespace between them. How do I trim the whitespace?

### MWE

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(gridExtra)

## Raster Setup
r <- raster::raster( matrix(runif(9),3,3) )
l <- rasterVis::levelplot( stack(r,r,r,r),
    layout=c(2,2),
    names=rep('',4),
    scales=list(draw=FALSE),
    between=list(x=0.2,y=-.8),
    margin=FALSE, main=NA)

## Adjust Heights
l$par.settings$layout.heights[
    c( 'bottom.padding',
       'top.padding',
       'key.sub.padding',
       'axis.xlab.padding',
       'key.axis.padding',
       'main.key.padding'
       ) ] <- -10

## Plot Grobs     
grobs <- arrangeGrob(grobs=list(l,l,l,l), ncol=2)
grid.arrange(grobs )
```

Note that this method does not work
[Remove white space between plots and table in grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141400/remove-white-space-between-plots-and-table-in-grid-arrange/32143553)

Answer (score 1):

Adjust these parameters

```
l$par.settings$layout.heights[
    c( 'bottom.padding',
       'top.padding',
       'key.sub.padding',
       'axis.xlab.padding',
       'key.axis.padding',
       'main.key.padding') ] <- -1
l$aspect.fill <- TRUE
```